# AddressPicker with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the addresspicker here http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html to auto complete an address form that I am developing.

I am totally new to web development and have started using twitter bootstrap with a couple of query plugins for form validation and a datepicker which is working fine, but have not idea how to incorporate the addresspicker into my page so I can use the callback function to populate the address part of my form.

Could someone help me or point me in the right direction. I have also come across this example, https://github.com/elmariachi111/jquery-addresspicker, but it does not include the form section.

Here is my code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <title>Add a member</title>  
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">

      /* Sticky footer styles
      -------------------------------------------------- */

      .top-margin
      {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .help-inline {
        color: #FF0000;
      }

    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container top-margin"> <div class="well text-center"><h1 class="muted">Add     a member</h1></div></div>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="well">
      <form id="signup" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="success.php">
        <legend>Member entry</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="first name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="last name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Home Telephone</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-phone"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="home number">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Mobile Number</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-mobile-phone"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="mobile number">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Join Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="span2" id="jdate"  name="jdate" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="span2" id="dofb" value="01-01-1980" name="dofb" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Proposed By</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    <select class="span2" name="pby">
                      <option selected>-</option>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                      <option>5</option>
                      <option>6</option>
                      <option>7</option>
                      <option>8</option>
                      <option>9</option>
                      <option>10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Seconded By</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    <select class="span2" name="sby">
                      <option selected>-</option>
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                      <option>5</option>
                      <option>6</option>
                      <option>7</option>
                      <option>8</option>
                      <option>9</option>
                      <option>10</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div id="gender" name="gender" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Male</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Female</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">BCF</label>
            <div class="controls">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="bcf" value="bcf" name="bcf">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->

        <legend>Address</legend>

        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Address Line 1</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="addressl1" name="addl1" placeholder="address line 1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Address Line 2</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="addl2" name="addl2" placeholder="address line 2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">City</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="city" name="city" placeholder="city">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">County</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="county" name="county" placeholder="county">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
        <div class="control-group ">
            <label class="control-label">Post Code</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="pcode" name="pcode" placeholder="post code">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->

        <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
          <div class="controls">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Create Member</button>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- Control-group -->
      </form>
    </div>
</div>

  <!-- Javascript placed at the end of the file to make the  page load faster -->
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#signup").validate({
                rules:{
                    gender:"required",
                    fname:"required",
                    lname:"required",
                    email:{
                            required:true,
                            email: true
                        }
                },
                messages: {
                     email:{
                            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                        }
                },

                errorClass: "help-inline"

            });

        });

        $('#jdate').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            todayBtn: 'linked'
        });
        $('#dofb').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            todayBtn: 'linked'
        });


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks for any help you can give me...
Luke

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in your head:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.addresspicker.js"></script>

        <script>
         $( "#addressl1" ).addresspicker();
        </script>
```

Make sure you download jquery.ui.addresspicker.js and place it in the same folder where index.html is.